# the $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries cannot have a repeated complex eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am having a hard time understanding why that a  $2 \times 2$ matrix with real entries can not have a repeated complex eigenvalue.

Comment: Complex eigenvalues always come in conjugate pairs.  If you have one complex eigenvalue, then its conjugate must be another eigenvalue.  That is already two of the possible two eigenvalues so there could not be any repeat.

Answer (score 1):

To find the eigenvalues of a matrix, we look at the zeros of its [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial). If our matrix has real entries, then the coefficients of the polynomial are real, so we know that any complex zeros must come in conjugate pairs. So, for $2\times 2$ matrices, our characteristic polynomial has either $0$ complex roots or $2$ complex roots. If any eigenvalue is non-real, then it is automatically complex (with non-zero imaginary part), and hence is not equal to its complex conjugate, which must also be a root of the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Let the complex repeated eigen value be $\lambda$. Then the characteristic polynomial is: $$(x-\lambda)(x-\lambda)=x^2-2\lambda x+{\lambda}^2$$Compare this with the general expression for the characteristic polynomial:$$x^2-tr(A)x+\det(A)=0$$
Now $tr(A)=2\lambda$ (a complex number). But $A$ is real!